# Script to copy entire row (not always the same row) from one sheet to another on Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script to copy one row from one sheet to another sheet in Google Sheet. But here is the catch, the row will not always be the same. The script would have to copy a specific row based on the cell selected

I am new to this but I was able to come up with the code below:

```
function copyRowsWithCopyTo() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Todays');
  
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet8');
  
  sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getrange(1, 1));
}
```

However I get an error when I try to run it: :TypeError: targetSheet.getrange is not a function
copyRowsWithCopyTo  @ macros.gs:9:

Comment: `getrange()` should be spelled `getRange()`  Spelling counts in programming [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer))

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way for my problem by doing some more digging on this website . Please see my code below:

```
function copyRowsWithCopyTo() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Todays');
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet 8');
  
  let row = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  let activeRow = sourceSheet.getRange( row ,1, 1 ,19);
  let last_row = targetSheet.getLastRow();
   
  activeRow.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange('A'+(last_row+1)+':Q'+(last_row+1)));

  sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
}
```

I also added a line at the end of the code to delete the active row.

Comment: If it works, then mark your question as resolved.